# DialogFlow from AsyncTask to RX

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

Im looking for a way to manage a Observable over a Asynctask in the request from the API of DialogFlow (AI.API from Google https://dialogflow.com)

Right now the code is everything in Kotlin
The normal request is the next one

```
val task = object : AsyncTask<String, Void, AIResponse>() {
        private var aiError: AIError? = null

        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String): AIResponse? {
            val request = AIRequest()
            val query = params[0]
            val event = params[1]

            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query))
                request.setQuery(query)
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event))
                request.setEvent(AIEvent(event))
            val contextString = params[2]
            var requestExtras: RequestExtras? = null
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contextString)) {
                val contexts = listOf(AIContext(contextString))
                requestExtras = RequestExtras(contexts, null)
            }

            try {
                return aiDataService?.request(request, requestExtras)
            } catch (e: AIServiceException) {
                aiError = AIError(e)
                return null
            }

        }

        override fun onPostExecute(response: AIResponse?) {
            if (response != null) {
                aiApiSuccess (response)
            } else {
                view.onError(R.string.natural_language_error)
            }
        }
    }
    task.execute(requestString, "", "")
```

I don't know if I doing wrong the request
Right now

```
return Observable.fromCallable<AIResponse> {
        val params = arrayOfNulls<String>(3)
        val request = AIRequest()
        val query = params[0]
        val event = params[1]

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(query))
            request.setQuery(requestString)
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(event))
            request.setEvent(AIEvent(event))
        val contextString = params[2]
        var requestExtras: RequestExtras? = null
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(contextString)) {
            val contexts = listOf(AIContext(contextString))
            requestExtras = RequestExtras(contexts, null)
        }

        try {
            aiDataService.request(request, requestExtras)
        } catch (e: AIServiceException) {
            Log.i("Error", "Error")
        }
            AIResponse()
        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

It make the request but all the objects are null always 
that doesn't happen with the Asynctask

Comment: then bottom line in the `Observable::fromCallable` method - `AIResponse()` is returning an new `AIResponse` object - the return of `aiDataService.request(request, requestExtras)` is ignored. Remove `AIResponse()` as the return type. Looking at the code all of your `if` statements will never work as your `params[]` has `null` entries - You need them to contain something first for lines like : `request.setQuery(requestString)` to execute, or if they're not required remove the unnecessary code.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will probably update this, to people starting with DialogFlow have an idea of how to do it